# Why is json.dumps with DjangoJSONEncoder returning a string for a Integer field?

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-serializer

So I have this code:

```
class JSONResponseJSONDumps(HttpResponse):
    """JSON response class."""
    def __init__(self, obj='', json_opts={}, mimetype="application/json", *args, **kwargs):
         content = json.dumps(obj, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
         super(JSONResponseJSONDumps,self).__init__(content, mimetype, *args, **kwargs)


class Equipment(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    volts = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    hertz = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    amps = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

//views.py

```
      data = {
             "serial": equipment.serial,
             "hertz": equipment.hertz,
             "volts": equipment.volts,
             "amps" : equipment.amps,
             }                                
      response = JSONResponseJSONDumps(data, {}, 'application/json')
```

I send this back to iOS. Now, I have this weird problem where amps is being sent as a integer, and iOS sees that, and in the case of Volts and Amps, it is being sent as String?!

This has happened to me in other models as well. Any ideas?!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility that this is an issue inside of your iOS app by downloading your json view with a browser?

Comment: I am using AFNetworking and RestKit.

Comment: I don't know what those are. Have you tried downloading the json manually with a browser?